# Trying to create leaflet map with click function using ajax to post lat lng coordinates into php file

Tags: php, ajax, leaflet

I'm trying to create Leaflet map that when the map is clicked on, it creates a marker and posts the coordinates in the console. Then the coordinates are posted via ajax to a php file and then inserted into a mysql database.

```
        var map;
    var centerlatlng = L.latLng(34.248987,-118.531891);
    var lat;
    var lng;
    var markerLatLng;


    $(document).ready(function (){  

$('.aPopOver').popover({
        'container': 'body'
});// this works        

var aLayerOne = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    key: 'f4cedc5a042746e8813e1db9697e92e5',
                    styleId: 22677,
                    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, Created @ <a href="http://www.csun.edu/csbs/departments/geography/">CSUN Geography</a>',
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    minZoom: 4
                });  


var aLayerTwo = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    key: 'f4cedc5a042746e8813e1db9697e92e5',
                    styleId: 82102,
                    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, Created @ <a href="http://www.csun.edu/csbs/departments/geography/">CSUN Geography</a>',
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    minZoom: 4
                });  

map = L.map('myMap', {
                center: centerlatlng,
                zoom:   12,
                layers: [aLayerOne]
            }); 
    // Define an EVENT for the map
```

map.on('click', function(e) {

```
    console.log("You clicked on the map !");
    console.info("lat = " + e.latlng.lat + " " + "long= " + e.latlng.lng);
    var lat = $(e.latlng.lat);
    var lng = $(e.latlng,lng);
    var markerLatLng = L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).addTo(map);



        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "post.php",
        data:{lat: lat},
        success:function()
            {
                alert("Post Successful!");
            }


    });                                                                                    
}); // end of map on click event    

// Add a Layers Control
var baseMaps = {
    "Default": aLayerOne,
    "Night Rider": aLayerTwo
};                  

L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);

// Add a Scale Control
L.control.scale().addTo(map);

// Add a Full Screen Control
// use  "new" in its construct
new L.Control.FullScreen().addTo(map);

// Add a Locate Control
// images folder must be within the same folder as L.Control.Locate.css file
```

}); // end document ready